# IcCube - AmChart scrollbar drag icons not showing

Tags: amcharts, iccube

In IcCube reporting,
I added an amchart, 
in the widget advanced properties, 
I set the Scrollbar.Hide Resize Grips to "no" in order to show the scroll...

The scroll is visible but not the drag icons...
if I look in chrome's debugger, I can see that it's looking for this file : undefineddragIcon.gif 404 (Not Found)

I tested on icCube's livedemo and the problem is the same...

What am I missing there ?
Txs in davance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path to images was not set in the icCube's amChart integration.

Will be fixed in the next release.